# Array of strings to array of array

Tags: powershell

Sometimes PowerShell is completely awesome and other times it is completely frustrating and unintuitive.  It is almost always an array that is causing me grief.

This time I have an array of strings.  I want to split each string on white space so that I end up with an array of arrays of strings.  I have tried this:

```
$data | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(@(), [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) }
```

But that just flattens everything into one large array of strings like `SelectMany` in C#.  I have also tried this:

```
$data | Select-Object { $_.Split(@(), [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) }
```

But that gives me an array of `PsCustomObject`.  I feel like this should be incredibly easy.  Am I missing something completely obvious?

Comment: `$data | ForEach-Object { ,$_.Split(@(), [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) }`

Comment: @PetSerAl - Of course, why didn't I think of that /s.  You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put unary comma (array) operator to prevent PowerShell to enumerate an array, returned by `Split` method:

```
$data | ForEach-Object { ,$_.Split(@(), [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?  What I do here is I loop through all of the elements in the array, and then I do the split and replace the current item with the returned `String[]` from the `Split()`:

```
$Outer = "hello there", "how are you?", "I'm good, thanks"

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Outer.Count; $i++) {
    $Outer[$i] = $Outer[$i].Split(" ")
}

$Outer[1][2]
# you?

$Outer[2][0]
# I'm
```